# Find all items where match (or like) a text in a Model within Mongoid in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I´m working in a project with Rails 4 and Mongodb as back-end helped by the wonderful gem 'Mongoid' and I want to find all items of my model 'Item' matching a search term using 'sql-like' too.

My model looks like:

```
class Item
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, :type => String
  field :importe, :type => BigDecimal
  field :tipo, :type => String  
end
```

Trying to do this in the controller but doesn´t works correctly:

```
Item.where(name: Regexp.new(".*"+params[:keywords]+".*"))
```

(where "params[keywords]" is the searchterm) because doesn´t returns anything when there are items with this name value.

How do I make this query?

Comment: why not `Item.where(name: /.*#{params[:keywords]}.*/)` because you can use interpolation inside a regex. also note this limits matches to having the correct keywords in order. so you could alter keywords to be something like `keywords = params[:keywords].split.join("?.*") << "?"` so your regex looks like `/.*this?.*is?.*a?.*test?.*/` that way it searchs for all the keywords instead of exactly these keywords in this order.

Comment: it doesn´t works irb(main):034:0> searchterm = 'Letra'
=> "Letra"
irb(main):035:0> Item.where(name: /.*#{searchterm}.*/)
=> #<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {"name"=>/.*Letra.*/}
  options:  {}
  class:    Item
  embedded: false>

Comment: what do you mean doesn't work? it clearly interpolated `'Letra'` as expected. You need to add `.to_a` at the end. `where` returns a criteria `to_a` will return the appropriate `Array` with the criteria applied. might I also suggest adding `i` to the end of the regex so that it ignores case e.g. `/.*#{searchterm}.*/i`

Comment: That `Item.where` should work fine. What specifically is in `params[:keywords]` and what documents do you expect it to find? BTW, you don't need those `.*`s in your regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Item.where({:name => "/#{params[:keywords]}/i"})
```

Comment: You might want to check the difference between `Regexp.new('pancakes').inspect` and `Regexp.new('/panckaes/').inspect`.

Comment: Doesn´t works  `irb(main):037:0> searchterm = 'Letra'
=> "Letra"`
`irb(main):038:0> Item.where({:name => Regexp.new("/.*#{searchterm}.*/")})
=> #<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {"name"=>/\/.*Letra.*\//}
  options:  {}
  class:    Item
  embedded: false>`

Comment: I updated my answer. Please try that. This also includes the i declarive, which makes the search case in-sensitive.

Comment: FYI, I'm not sure if you know this or not, but the query will not actually be executed unless you apply some type of iterator to your query. Meaning Item.where(name: 'test') is going to return the criteria selector so it can continue to be chained further on. You won't see results until you actually try and iterate over the object. Example: abort Item.where(name: 'test').all.inspect

Comment: Hi Venice, I don´t know why doesn´t works when I tested yesterday but now it works!! Your answer was correct! Sorry for the wrong comment

Answer (score 4):

In ruby rails, we need to use this:

```
condition = /#{params[:keywords]}/i
Item.where(:name => condition)
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for me when I go to this question again in the future.

```
Item.where(name: /.*phon.*/i).to_a
```